# Where to send the authorization code generated through authentication using Spring Security with a Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring-security

I have successfully managed to authorize a user and obtain an authorization code, which is shown in the URL along with a state.

The problem is, I'm not sure what the next step would be in the flow here. This is where I have the redirect-uri set to: 
`http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}` where it will append the `authorization code` and `state`, but it just takes me back to the login screen with this error:

*Your login attempt was not successful, try again.*

Reason: `An error occurred while sending the Access Token Request: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

I've basically been trying to follow the code on https://github.com/pivotal-cf/identity-sample-apps/tree/spring-boot-2.1/authcode.

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.3.  Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Generally that error comes from not being able to find the certificate that will be used to sign a token.  So is your server creating a JWT that will be returned?

Comment: Have you seen this yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore?rq=1